# Android audio looping

Tags: android

Although a seasoned developer, I'm new to Android, and am wanting to develop an app to loop between user defineable sections of audio recorded via Android's mic in.

I'm wanting as low latency as possible when the loop point is hit (i.e. miminal time to seek the start point of the section and resume playback).

I'm after some general recommendations such as:

audio file format
which classes should I be considering for playback (e.g. soundpool, media player etc)

Thanks for any advice

Dave

Answer (score 6):

You can use Media player and an OnCompletetionListener like this:

```
    MediaPlayer mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yoursound);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.nextsound);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }

    });
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

As for sound file types I've never noticed much of a difference between any of them. I tend to stick with .mp3 or .ogg though just because the file size tends to be smaller for those than for .wav.

Edit: Ahh I see, If you are wanting to play the whole audio file over and over you just need to call setLooping(true) like this:

```
    MediaPlayer mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yoursound);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

If you are trying to play the full audio file once, then loop some small section of it over and over you can use the .seekTo() method inside the completionlistener like this:

```
    MediaPlayer mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yoursound);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yoursound);
            mp.seekTo(3000); //3 seconds in
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }

    });
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! If I'm understanding this correctly, what this describes is a situation where the completion of R.raw.yoursound will trigger the playback of R.raw.nextsound, which isn't quite what I'm after. I'd like to be able to instruct the playback object to resume playback from a specific point (loop start) in the file when a certain point (loop end) is reached- within the one soundfile. There's always the chance that I'm missing something subtle here though!

Comment: OK Tim, thank you- Given that it's the **completion** listener that triggers the loop back, this implies that the end point must always be the end of the file, rather than an arbitrary point within the the sound file- I'm wondering if the audiotrack class might be more what I'm looking for where I can getPlaybackHeadPosition() during playback to identify loop start and end points then use setLoopPoints() to repeat that section- have you used this? Can you see any problems with this appoach?

Comment: I have not used that class before. But it seems like that would be a fine approach to me.